# google apps script web app dynamic list from form

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script web app that contains an HTML form with a couple of drop-down lists.  When the user submits their choices, a function looks them up in a Google spreadsheet and returns corresponding values in an array.  This array could have any length, and I am having trouble getting it to display as an HTML list without having a set list length.

I have this GAS script:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function discern(formObject) {

  var stage = formObject.stage;
  var service = formObject.service;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var array = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][1].indexOf(stage) > -1) {
      if(data[i][2].indexOf(service) > -1) {
        array.push(data[i][0]);
      }
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<script>
  function printList(array) {
    var div = document.getElementById('results');
    var list = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      list.append('<li>' + array[i] + '</li>');
    }
    list.append('</ul>');  
  }

</script>

<form id="myForm">

  <h3>Farming Stage</h3><br>
  Select your farming stage.<br>
  <select name="stage">
  <option etc etc etc
  </select><br>

  <h3>Services</h3><br>
  Select the service for which you are looking<br>
  <select name="service">
  <option value= etc etc etc</option>
  </select><br>

  <br><input type="button" value="Discern"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(printList)
          .discern(this.parentNode)"/>
</form>
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

(I've replaced some sections with "etc" to save space.  The form itself is not the issue.)

Anyway, right now the app returns nothing.  Earlier I had the printList function as:

```
function printList(array) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML =
    '<ul><li>' + array[0] + 
    '</li><li>' + array[1] + 
    '</li><li>' + array[2] + 
    '</li><li>' + array[3] + 
    '</li><li>' + array[4] + 
    '</li></ul>';
  }
```

This version worked, but it was limited to 5 list slots, and the unused slots showed up as "undefined," which was annoying.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Was I close with the 'for' loop in my printList function?  Is there another simple way to go about this?  I would really appreciate any help or feedback.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: In case anyone is interested, here's the app with the older, crappier version of the printList function: [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwp9daz7BWM_lzc5U-zQcEMpqG53776ucEZo-56FWhWIf1Ill9i/exec)

Comment: should the `list` be added to the div's html?

Comment: Yes!  Definitely.  I must have had that in there at some point in my stumbling around, but I'll try again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, it worked when I did it this way:

```
...<br><input type="button" value="Discern"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(showThings)
          .discern(this.parentNode)"/>
</form>

<p>List of services:</p>
<ul id="things">
    <li>Waiting...</li>
</ul>

<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
function showThings(array) {
  var list = $('#things');
  list.empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    list.append('<li>' + array[i] + '</li>');
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the div `results` do you mean to append the list to the html?

```
<script>
  function printList(array) {
    var div = document.getElementById('results');
    var list = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<ul>');
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      list.append('<li>' + array[i] + '</li>');
    }
    list.append('</ul>');  
    // ? 
    div.innerHTML = list.getContent();
  }

</script>
```

**edit**  Also I think you need to `getContents` of the html Object.

You could not use the `HTMLService`. Personally I never got it to work the way I wanted it to when I used it. (a couple years ago).

Why not use your loop and just append the string to the div like this.

```
  <script>
      function printList(array) {
        var div = document.getElementById('results');
        var list = '<ul>');
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          list += '<li>' + array[i] + '</li>';
        }
        list += '</ul>';  
        div.innerHTML = list;
      }

    </script>
```

Comment: This did not work; nothing happens at all with this code.  Thank you for the suggestion, though.  About half the time I ask my ridiculous newbie questions on here, no one answers at all.  Do you have any other ides of why this might not be working?

Comment: @Bill updated the answer.What about not using the `HtmlService`?

Comment: Thanks for following up on this.  I tried your script without the HtmlService, and again there is no output at all.  As for the .getContents idea, the following code is working without it, so I don't think that is the problem:  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
    <script>
      function printList(array) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML =
        '<ul><li>' + array[0] + 
        '</li><li>' + array[1] + 
        '</li><li>' + array[2] + 
        '</li><li>' + array[3] + 
     '</li><li>' + array[4] + 
    '</li></ul>';
  }
</script>

Comment: Perhaps "templates" are the answer: (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: So I tried getting rid of the `printList` script and adding the following "templated HTML" below my form HTML:   `<ul>
<? var array; ?>
<? for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { ?>
      <li><?= array[i] ?></li>
<? } ?>`    Now the form does not appear, and all I get is the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined."  Of course, the `array` variable is supposed to be returned by the server-side script when the user submits the form, but now for reasons that are unclear to me, there is no form and this script is insisting on running immediately.